# gulp task issue with nodejs v10.3.0 : src\node_contextify.cc:629: Assertion `args[1]->IsString()' failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, node-modules

I recently updated my nodejs version to 10.30.0. Everything works fine. But my gulp build task not working which was working fine on older version(9.X). This is what I am getting.

```
 gulp[11376]: src\node_contextify.cc:629: Assertion `args[1]->IsString()' failed.
 1: node::DecodeWrite
 2: node::DecodeWrite
 3: uv_loop_fork
 4: v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeDecoder::Decode
 5: v8::internal::RegExpImpl::Exec
 6: v8::internal::RegExpImpl::Exec
 7: v8::internal::RegExpImpl::Exec
 8: 00000384E1284281
```

Comment: Have you reinstalled your modules after upgrading?

Comment: reinstalled gulp related packages

Comment: Tried reinstalling all node modules.Still the same

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Just run command

```
npm install natives
```

Comment: I think they fixed this issue on 10.7.0 It is working now

Comment: This did it for me. I then ran `npm install` afterwards and all worked. I'm running node 10.9.0.

Comment: + `npm install` + `npm audit fix` was required to get gulp working again.

Comment: You may need to do an additional ```npm cache clean --force``` and then ```npm install``` and then ```npm install natives```. That was the combination in my case.

Comment: Bear in mind that this is far from an ideal solution. Read the warning about the use of this package on it's NPM page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/natives The real solution to this is probably to upgrade to current versions of Node and node-sass.

Comment: For me ( node -v => 10.15.1 ) works:  `npm cache clean --force`  then `npm install`, but without `npm install natives` ( installing natives throwing another error )

Comment: I was receiving this error with a project using Visual Studio 2019 v16.1.0. Running npm install natives as per this answer solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: its worked for me .... thank you so much. wasted 2+ hours and finally, just single command solved an issue.

Comment: This actually fixed my issue after spending entire day!

Answer (score 16):

I have had two different solutions work in two different workspaces. The first after updating to node 10.6.0 required me to use [this method](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2162#issuecomment-384885950):

```
$rm -rf node_modules
$rm -rf package-lock.json
$npm cache clean
$npm install
```

The second workspace wouldn't work with the above, though I did try it first, it required me to reinstall all my gulp dependencies then run npm audit fix. For example:

```
$npm install --dev gulp gulp-sass gulp-autoprefixer
$npm audit fix
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: with later versions of node you have to use  $npm cache clean --force to delete the cache, or on Windows, delete the C:\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache folder. This fixed the issue for me

Comment: `npm install natives` didn't immediately solve my problems, but thanks @dwilli manually deleting folders and following this solution's advice worked for me

Answer (score 5):

node version compatible problem, try use node version<=9.11.2.

Comment: this is what actually works. switched to 9.4.0 from >= 10.1.
"npm install natives" didn't do it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.  Deleting node_modules and re-running `npm install`, to re-install the modules listed in package.json, did work for me.

Comment: unfortunately, it is not working for me. I switched back to old version for running build

Comment: I think they fixed this issue on 10.7.0 It is working now`

Answer (score 1):

Just run these two commands.

1. remove `node_modules` folder

> rm -r node_modules

2. And Install only natives dependencies.

> npm install natives

Answer (score 1):

The top-voted answer says to run `npm install natives`, but the natives package has been deprecated. One of the commentors says there's a warning at [npmjs.com/package/natives](https://www.npmjs.com/package/natives). But I feel it's more than a warning. Quoting it:

> This module relies on Node.js's internals and will break at some point. Do not use it, and update to graceful-fs@4.x.

When the author of the package says: "Do not use it", you should probably heed their advice.

Answer (score 0):

`npm install natives`
This works with Windows 10 64 Bit

Answer (score 0):

My system:

1. Windows 10
2. Node 10.15.3

Steps:

1. npm update
2. npm i natives
3. npm i
4. npm audit fix

The order is required.

My packages after when I have updated via command "npm update":

```
{
  "name": "your name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.2.6",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-async-to-promises": "^1.0.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "v4.0.0-beta",
    "chartist-webpack": "^0.9.5-0",
    "d3": "^4.13.0",
    "d3.js": "^0.0.2-security",
    "datalist-polyfill": "^1.23.3",
    "dimple-js": "^2.1.4",
    "future-tabs": "^1.3.2",
    "gridstack": "0.2.6",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-cache-bust": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-connect": "^5.7.0",
    "gulp-cssmin": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-extname": "^0.2.2",
    "gulp-postcss": "^7.0.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-sequence": "^0.4.6",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.5",
    "ionicons": "^3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "jquery-ui-touch-punch": "^0.2.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "md5": "^2.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "natives": "^1.1.6",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^2.0.0",
    "promise-polyfill": "6.0.2",
    "semaphore-async-await": "^1.5.1",
    "url-search-params-polyfill": "^2.0.3",
    "vanilla-modal": "^1.6.5",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0",
    "webpack-stream": "^4.0.3",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problem too with `gulp`

`` gulp build[30580]: c:\ws\src\node_contextify.cc:635: Assertion `args[1]->IsString()' failed.
 1: 00007FF6F86BC6AA v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+4506 ``

`npm install natives` solved the problem in `windows 64`

Answer (score 0):

using node **v10.16.0**

`npm install natives`

`npm audit fix`

Answer (score 0):

### npm (not yarn) solution

1. Update your npm packages
2. `npm rebuild` // Install will likely work too?
3. You'll likely get a new error about 'parallels'
4. Follow this guide (not mine): https://timonweb.com/javascript/how-to-fix-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined-error/

**Why?** Gulp v3 + Node v12 are incompatible with each other. Don't try updating to Gulp v4 for the purpose of fixing this issue, as there are breaking changes (unless you wanna rewrite your code). Don't downgrade Node because it's not scalable and you may run into other issues. You'll have to upgrade *eventually*.